# Start a script on boot with dotenv library linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I want to run a python script that uses the dotenv library and a .env file.

I have tried using a systemd service but it keeps saying I don't have the right modules installed.

**service.py**

```
[Unit]
Description=Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 <path-to-script>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: can you please also post the content of `/usr/bin/python3 <path-to-script>`?